# react-router-dom v6 params only numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want add number regex in may param in react-router-dom v6. it work fin in v5 like it:

```
 <Route path="list/:id(\d+)" element={<MyComponent/>} />
```

but it not work in v6.

Comment: why don't you pass that regex to your `MyComponent` via props?

Comment: @Amr i want it work as route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are not supported in `react-router-dom@6`.

See [What Happened to Regexp Routes Paths?](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths)

> Regexp route paths were removed for two reasons:
>
> 1. Regular expression paths in routes raised a lot of questions for v6's ranked route matching. How do you rank a regex?
> 2. We were able to shed an entire dependency (path-to-regexp) and cut the package weight sent to your user's browser significantly. If it
>    were added back, it would represent 1/3 of React Router's page weight!

You can use the `useParams` hook and test the `id` param in the component.

Example:

```
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!/\d+/.test(id)) {
      navigate(-1);
    }
  }, [id, navigate]);

  ...
};
```